# Display standard text on label?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've this label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.Competition}" ContentStringFormat="League: {0}"/>
```

I need to display each time the value `League:` anyway, if the value is not binded I can't see any League: on the gui, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an appropriate ContentTemplate:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.Competition}">
    <Label.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="League: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Label.ContentTemplate>
</Label>
```

Or shorter, set the Binding's FallbackValue:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.Competition, FallbackValue=''}"
       ContentStringFormat="League: {0}">
```

Comment: I know, the only thing that I don't appreciate of wpf is that too much code for achieve a simple target

Answer (score 0):

Either make sure your ViewModel or bound property returns null or empty string, or use a separate `Label`.